# Linear Algebra - direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let ${V}=\mathbb{R}^3$, and define

${V}_1=\{{\textbf{x}\in{V}\mid x_1+x_2+x_3=0}$}, and 
${V}_2=\{{\textbf{x}\in{V}\mid x_1=x_2=x_3}$}.

We know that $V$ is a direct sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$. 
Can we find an example by replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by some other field $\mathbb{F}$ such that $V$ fails to be the direct sum?

So we need to find a field such that at least one vector in the new field cannot be written as a sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$. I am stuck on this...
Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Any Finite field will work

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Say for example, we take $\mathbb{Z}_3$. I don't quite understand what it looks like as a field. Is it like a set {0,1,2}?

Comment: It's $\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{2}  \}$. You can view as Natural line rapped around with multiples of $3$ coinciding with $0$. Here, the bar notation represents a class.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. I don't understand why taking finite field would make it a failure to be a direct sum.

Comment: Is it because if we take {1,1,1} or {2,2,2}, they cannot be written as a sum?

Comment: Correct. You are thinking in the correct direction. Also, there is nothing special about $\mathbb{Z}_3$. You can cook many examples.Wish you luck!!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Kumar : not any finite field, there is something special about $\mathbb F_3$ in that example.

Comment: @Max Okay. But then, it would be the only field where we get a counterexample.

Comment: @Kumar  No, for dimension $3$ we get counterexamples exactly in fields of characteristic $3$; for dimension $n$ counterexamples exactly in fields of characteristic $\mid n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb F=\mathbb Z_3$, then they fail to be a direct sum, since $(1,1,1)$ belongs to both of them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please explain a bit more? I don't understand what ${{Z}_3}^3$ means as a field.

Comment: It was a typo. I meant $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: All right. But does ${Z}_3$ have order? I only met this as a set...and I am not quite sure why it fails to be a direct sum in this case. Thank you.

Comment: No finite fieald is ordered. ANd I already told you in my answer why it fails to be a direct sum: because $(1,1,1)\in V_1\cap V_2$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why $(1,1,1)\in \textit{V}_1$. 1+1+1 is not 0.

Comment: Yes, it is, in $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much.